# Angular Js expression in expression

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

I have an angular expression

```
<td>{{quote.IsRequired ?'Yes':'No'}} </td>
```

It will show yes or no  value in table.

I have one more expression `{{quote.Type}}` , this will have any "String"

I have to show this string with  Yes in my table.like this Yes - String ('yes' {{quote.Type}}).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just append it with a plus (+).

```
<td>{{quote.IsRequired ? 'Yes - ' + quote.Type : 'No'}}</td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much as a i am beginner , you saved my day :)